# Function `print` does not wait for the function before it

Tags: python, tkinter

In my Python program, I defined a function like this:

```
def engine_input_number_of_students_and_student_information(self, window):
        self.__input.input_number_of_students(self, window)
        print(self.number_of_students)
```

and the function `input_number_of_students` was defined in class Input like this:

```
class Input:
    # Function to ask user to input number of student.
    # Print error and force the user to re-input if wrong data is given.
    def input_number_of_students(self, engine, window):
        sub = tk.Toplevel(master=window)
        sub.title("Number of students")
        sub.resizable(height=False, width=False)
        window.eval(f'tk::PlaceWindow {str(sub)} center')
        frm1 = tk.Frame(master=sub)
        frm1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
        lbl = tk.Label(text="Enter number of students:", master=frm1)
        number_of_students_var = tk.StringVar()
        ent = tk.Entry(width=3, master=frm1, textvariable=number_of_students_var)
        lbl.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5)
        ent.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5)
        frm2 = tk.Frame(master=sub)
        frm2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=5, pady=5)

        def ok():
            number_of_students = int(number_of_students_var.get())
            if number_of_students < 0:
                messagebox.showinfo(message="Error: number of students must be non-negative")
                ent.delete(-1, tk.END)
            else:
                engine.number_of_students = number_of_students
                print(engine.number_of_students)
                sub.destroy()

        ok_btn = tk.Button(text="OK", master=frm2, command=ok)
        ok_btn.pack(ipadx=5, ipady=5)
```

But when I try to test the program, the `print` function was executed even when I haven't input anything for the `number_of_students` (it prints 0, obviously). And I don't know why.

Comment: So your actual question is, how do you hang in `input_number_of_students()` until someone clicks the button and enters a number of students?

Comment: Try `print(message, flush=True)`. It's not about "waiting", it's about flushing to stdout

Comment: I was trying to wait for the user to input a value, then that value is printed. For example, when I input "2" in the entry, then press "OK", it would print 2 after that, but ```print``` was executed before I even input anything

Comment: Oh I saw my problem. The problem is that ```input_number_of_students``` only created a sub-window, and considered done after that, not after pressing "OK". What I would like to do is that the function is done after I input some value and press "OK"

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy yes, that is what I am trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `input_number_of_students` doesn't wait for a user input, it creates the tkinter window, the input box and the button but it doesn't wait anywhere for the user to input something. So the program moves onto the next line which is the `print` line and prints a `0`.

To fix this you need to call `print` from the callback function `ok` or use the `wait_variable` keyword.

```
class Input:
    # Function to ask user to input number of student.
    # Print error and force the user to re-input if wrong data is given.
    def input_number_of_students(self, engine, window):
        sub = tk.Toplevel(master=window)
        sub.title("Number of students")
        sub.resizable(height=False, width=False)
        window.eval(f'tk::PlaceWindow {str(sub)} center')
        frm1 = tk.Frame(master=sub)
        frm1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
        lbl = tk.Label(text="Enter number of students:", master=frm1)
        number_of_students_var = tk.StringVar()
        ent = tk.Entry(width=3, master=frm1, textvariable=number_of_students_var)
        lbl.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5)
        ent.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5)
        frm2 = tk.Frame(master=sub)
        frm2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=5, pady=5)

        def ok():
            number_of_students = int(number_of_students_var.get())
            if number_of_students < 0:
                messagebox.showinfo(message="Error: number of students must be non-negative")
                ent.delete(-1, tk.END)
            else:
                engine.number_of_students = number_of_students
                print(engine.number_of_students)
                sub.destroy()

        ok_btn = tk.Button(text="OK", master=frm2, command=ok)
        ok_btn.pack(ipadx=5, ipady=5)
        #I'm guessing this is the variable you modify?
        ok_btn.wait_variable(engine.number_of_students_var)
```

Comment: Oh, it worked well with ```wait_variable```. The variable that I want to modify is ```engine.number_of_students```. Thank you very much!

Comment: Using `wait_variable` in this case does not work if user closes the toplevel using the close button on the title bar without entering anything.  Better use `wait_window()` instead.